# Displaying the Indian currency symbol on a website

Tags: html, currency, symbols

This symbol for the rupee, the currency of India, was approved by the Union Cabinet on 15 July 2010. How can I display it on a website?

[image: Indian currency symbol]

Comment: Interesting. Note, U+20B9 is an unassigned code point in Unicode 5.2 - it has been accepted (as the text indicates) for inclusion into Unicode hopefully in the near future. Cool looking symbol. (Unicode accepted list: http://www.unicode.org/alloc/Pipeline.html)

Comment: Check this: [Comprehensive Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37643800/2142994)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty rectanglar box is displayed instead of the rupee symbol in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643675/empty-rectanglar-box-is-displayed-instead-of-the-rupee-symbol-in-html)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?filename=8377

Answer (score 21, accepted):

WebRupee is a web API for the Indian currency symbol. It provides a simple, cross browser method for using the Rrupee symbol on your webpage, blog or anywhere on the web.

Here is a method for printing the Indian currency symbol:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webrupee.com/font">
    <script src=http://cdn.webrupee.com/js type=”text/javascript”></script>
</head>
<body>
    Rupee Symbol: <span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span> 200
```

This means if somebody copies text from your site and pastes it somewhere else, he will see Rs and not some other or blank character.

You can now also use the new Rupee unicode symbol — U+20B9 INDIAN RUPEE SIGN. It can be used in this manner:

```
<span class="WebRupee">&#x20B9;</span> 500
```

Just include the following script and it will update all the "Rs" / "Rs." for you:

```
<script src="http://cdn.webrupee.com/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: aren't we talking about the new Rupee symbol?

Comment: and I see this does not work on my FF 3.6 http://i.imgur.com/V8fnG.png go fix it.

Comment: @Ankit y u pasting image?? i have tasted it..u must be doing some mistake

Comment: This won't work in Mozilla because for some weird "security" reason, they made a decision to only show fonts that are from the same domain.

Comment: Also, the CDN js from this organization gives a "stack overflow" problem in IE, as described in the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561984/stack-overflow-at-line-0

Comment: webrupee.com doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 100):

The HTML entity for the Indian rupee sign is `&#8377;` (₹). Use it like you would `&copy;` for the copyright sign. For more, read [Wikipedia's article on the rupee sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign).

Comment: whats the browser support of these currency signs? does they work till IE7?

Comment: I realized that rupee symbol does not appear in several browsers. Do we need to install a ttf file or update the browser?

Answer (score 43):

If you are using [font awesome icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/), then you can use this:

To import font-awesome:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Usage:

```
Current Price: <i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 400.00
```

will show as:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Its best even if computer don't have font

Comment: just use <i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 400.00 line its enough

Comment: thanks for this the currency unicode crashed in one of the 5 pc i checked it in but this was a life saver.

Comment: the best answer till so far, also working on any bootstrap theme.

Answer (score 18):

Please try the following solution:

```
<span style='font-family:Arial;'>&#8377;</span>
```

This will be displayed as : ₹

Answer (score 17):

Use this CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'rupee';
    src: url('rupee_foradian-1-webfont.eot');
    src: local('Ã¢ËœÂº'), url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,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)
    format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Declare it wherever required like this:

```
<span style="font-family:rupee;font-size:20px">R</span>
```

Answer (score 11):

It will take more than an year (or two) for the universal acceptance.

1. Unicode consortium approves the char-code.
2. Fonts are updated to include this symbol
3. Browsers/OS are updated to include new fonts and then only it is visible on every browser on earth.

Creating custom fonts by using arbitrary code-base and (forcefully) embedding them in every web-pages is discouraged for Website. (for desktop applications it may be acceptable). Although your solution may be acceptable; I would not advice just for the sake of one symbol! Loading a font file makes web-pages slower.

By the time it is advised to use **icon-sets** for rupee symbol. Prepare a set of icons with sizes 12x8, 16x12, 32x32 that you can incorporate in-line using `<img>` tag.

E.g [image] 5000/- (i just resized the image; it should have been re-sampled for given size for better results)

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGbfO.png" width="8" height="10">
```

Note: **This is what Wikipedia does. it uses [png/svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign) file.** Check the [infobox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tata_Consultancy_Services) here.

Comment: yah.. my frnds upvoted me and I got score of 1,402! u too go and make frnds on SO instead of FB.
What i described here is the best thing to do rather. There is an HTML way if you can read in my answer. `Creating custom fonts by using arbitrary code-base and (forcefully) embedding them in web-pages is highly discouraged for Website.` But that cannot guarantee your page will display on all web browsers; even that's an unnecessary when you can have IMG! It does not make sense to use BIG FONT FILE for just one symbol. You want scalable graphic - choose SVG!

Comment: from the revisions of this quetion, seems like you just wanted to promote your `WebRupee`

Comment: and now I see they even have Wiki page ( http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Webrupee&action=history ) created few days back. viral marketing. although your solution is acceptable. but i would not advice just for the sake of one symbol! prefer IMG.

Comment: @Ankit: do you really think using image is better alternative ?

Comment: @Rakesh Can you list down benefits u get with a font symbol? for Machines and Humans both! For humans having image vs font is no difference. For machines having image means less computing, less bandwidth, faster webpage rendering. (this argument is valid unless the FONTS with Rs are available in every OS!)

Answer (score 10):

Just type `<del>&#2352;</del>`  in your web page.

Answer (score 8):

There are two html entity code : `&#x20b9; &#8377;`

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with [**Intl.NumberFormat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) native API.

```js
const number = 123456.78;

// India uses thousands/lakh/crore separators
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'INR'
}).format(number));
```

Comment: Thank you. This did more than I needed!

Answer (score 5):

use this new unicode char: `&#x20b9;`

Answer (score 5):

best way copy the ₹ symbol and paste it.

Comment: is there an html symbolic reference for it though?

Comment: @Nelles [List of Unicode Characters of Category “Currency Symbol”](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Sc)

Answer (score 1):

Image approach is not bad either. It hardly takes 400Bytes.
Download from here https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJZ9m.png

```
<span class="rupee"></span>
```

Well i found it better than webrupee. 
For colors edit the image as below

```
    .rupee{
    background-position:left;
    width: 10px; 
    height: 14px;
    background-image: url('rupee.png');
    display:block; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be sought of a temporary solution.
Unicode has accepted `U+20B9` as Indian rupee symbol soon all systems will update themselves

Comment: I think "soon" is a bit optimistic, seeing as it's *fonts* that have to get updated. This will take a while.

Answer (score 0):

WebRupee API Available Here:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jagansindia.in/webrupee" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can also read full details [here](http://web.jagansindia.in/2013/09/webrupee-api-is-back/)

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY INR v1.2

A simple jQuery plug-in for convert Rs. to standard Indian rupee symbol through out the web page. Simple to use  and simple instillation

The Indian Rupee sign is the currency sign: ₹ for the Indian Rupee, the official currency of India. Designed by D. Udaya Kumar, it was presented to the public by the Government of India on 15 July 2010,[1] following its selection through an “open” competition among Indian residents. Before its adoption, the most commonly used symbols for the rupee were Rs, Re or, if the text was in an Indian language, an appropriate abbreviation in that language. The new sign relates solely to the Indian rupee; other countries that use a rupee, such as Sri Lanka, Pakistan and Nepal, still use the generic U+20A8 ₨ rupee sign character.
The design resembles both the Devanagari letter "र" (ra) and the Latin capital letter "R", with a double horizontal line at the top.

Instillation:

1. Download the “jQueryINR_v1.2.zip” and extract.
2. copy images (“rupee.svg,  rupee.gif”) to your images folder.
3. cope scripts folder to your project path or else copy the .js files to your script folder.
4. Download the “jQueryINR_v1.2.zip” and extract.
5. copy images (“rupee.svg,  rupee.gif”) to your images folder.
6. cope scripts folder to your project path or else copy the .js files to your script folder.
7. Include jQuery min and jQuery Ui to your page  first

   eg: 
       
      NB: use jQuery stable version only
8. include the “indianRupee_v1.2.js” and “indianRupee_ctrl.js” after the jQuery library
   eg:
9. Use Span tag to wrap Rs through out the web it will replace with the symbol
   eg: Rs 1280000/-

Source:

Pay Him Rs 1280000/-

Pay Him Rs 528500/-

Pay Him Rs 1250/-

## Pay Him Rs 1280000/-

Result:

```
   http://romy.theqtl.com/rupeePlugin/
```

Plug-in Options:

$("body").indianRupee({
targets:"span",// use  as default we can also use [p, div, h1 , li etc...]
vector:"on"//[on/off] of [true/false] NB: {vector not support in Internet Explore }
});

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with simple **HTML** entity code.

```css
.ex{
color:green;
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
Example 1 : <span class="ex">&#x20b9;1200/-</span><br>
Example 2 : <span class="ex">&#8377;3545/-</span><br>
Example 3 : <span class="ex">&#2352;134/-</span> *Is not the exact Rupee symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

Just In Case.
If you are binding amount to a ASP.Net label then you can display rupee sign like below

```
lblAmount.Text = "&#8377;"+ YourDataTable.Rows[rowindex]["AmountColumnName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using ASCII in HTML**

```
<p>Rupee sign: &#8377;</p>
```

**Using UNICODE character in HTML**

```
<p>Rupee sign: &#x20B9;</p>
```

**Using CSS**

```
<style>
.inr-sign::before{
content:"\20B9";
}
// Or use with ::after
.inr-sign::after{
content:"\20B9";
}
</style>

<span class="inr-sign"></span>
```

**Using Font Awesome**

The icon name for rupee symbol is “fa-rupee-sign”

```
<i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>
```