# Rupee symbol in mail

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I am using PHP mailer to send mails to my clients. I need to insert the Rupee symbol in the body of the mails.

[image: Rupee symbol]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What is said about [the Rupee symbol on web sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598085/how-to-add-indian-currency-symbol-in-your-website) holds (even more) true for mail clients: It will take some time (years) until versions of the standard fonts with the new symbol has made it to every client machine.

There are workarounds for web pages, but none of them is a good idea to use in E-Mails. I would use the currency code `INR` in E-Mails for the time being.

Comment: @Mohan unless you can guarantee that the right fonts are installed on each client, you're going to have to wait (or use an image based workaround like shown in the other question.)

Answer (score 5):

Check this [link](http://www.labnol.org/india/indian-rupee-added-to-unicode/17919/).Unicode Version 6.0 includes rupee symbol.

Comment: This will work only if the font on every client machine contains the symbol. It is not a feasible solution at this moment.

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is insert an `<img src...>` into the email body pointing to the rupee symbol image. make sure you turn the html headers in the mail on before doing this.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Entity (decimal) code worked for me for ₹

```
&#8377;
```

Some HTML and UTF codes are available :

```
HTML Entity (decimal)               -  &#8377;
HTML Entity (hex)                   -  &#x20b9;
UTF-8 (hex)                         -  0xE2 0x82 0xB9 (e282b9)
UTF-8 (binary)                      -  11100010:10000010:10111001
UTF-16 (hex)                        -  0x20B9 (20b9)
UTF-16 (decimal)                    -  8,377
UTF-32 (hex)                        -  0x000020B9 (20b9)
UTF-32 (decimal)                    -  8,377
C/C++/Java source code              -  "\u20B9"
Python source code                  -  u"\u20B9"
How to type in Microsoft Windows    -  Alt +20B9
```

Answer (score -5):

Rupee Symbol unicode has not yet released. since we are using some of plugins to display rupee symbols in web pages. Once unicode character is released then it is possible to use that code to display rupee in email as well as web sites.

Comment: [Unicode 6.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/) includes the Rupee symbol and was released a while ago now.

Comment: others gave more accurate answers and you accepted your own not to award with a bounty - pathetic

Comment: So this can be done as a way to escape from rewarding the bounty? I thought the bounty is always gone whether or not you accept someone's question!