# Is there a way to display alt symbol if client doesn't support a symbol in html newsletter

Tags: html, user-interface, outlook, symbols, newsletter

I am new to UI and HTML newsletters

I got stuck up with a problem. I have to display a rupee symbol in HTML newsletter (`&#8377;`). But not all mail clients, especially outlook 2007 support unicode standard 6.0. Is there a way to display Rs (`&#8360;`) instead of the previous, if it is not supported. (In short, a way to find, if a symbol is (supported) displayed or not. If not, display an alt symbol)

I cannot use an Image

Thanks in advance

EDITED:

I just found a quick fix at [Displaying the Indian currency symbol on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598085/displaying-the-indian-currency-symbol-on-a-website). use <del>र</del> instead of ₹ Though it is not exact, it works

Answer (score 0):

With HTML alone you can't detect a user agent/operating system and to chose what content to display. You'll need JavaScript.

Example using the `navigator` object to detect client's browser

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (/A_Specific_Agent_Name[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent))
    document.write("Your browser/mail client can display &#8377;")
else
    document.write(Your browser/mail client can display Rs")
</script>
```

More details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is not it (rupee symbol) present in UTF? Or do your clients not support UTF???

Comment: In outlook 2007, if a mail is received in utf-8,  I always need to change the
encoding setting to something different in Outlook 2007, and then change it
back to utf-8 in order to be able to see the Swedish Ã¥, Ã¤ and Ã¶ characters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if Outlook 2007 supports [webfonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography#Web_fonts), but if it does, I suggest you use a font of your own to display that symbol. That way you don't change encodings, just use a font with a glyph for `&#8377;`.

Some online free fonts from Google: http://www.google.com/webfonts

If you need to include all resources of HTML into the mail you probably know that this is posible assigning a Context-ID to the attachment (it's a header you assign to the body part) and using the Context-ID URL like this: `<img src="cid:what_you_put_in_the_header">`