# website design issue to replace rupees with new rupee symbol

Tags: css, web

How to include new Indian  rupee symbol on designing a website?

```
<span class="add-on">**Rupees**</span><input id="prependedInput" type="text" style="width:67px"></div>
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="float: none; margin-left: -3px;"><span class="caret"></span></a>
```

I want to replace **rupees** with new its new symbol how to do that? Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: almost duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598085/displaying-the-indian-currency-symbol-on-a-website

Comment: Was it that hard to google "rupee website"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)There is a css for this...

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webrupee.com/font">

 <span class="WebRupee">Rs</span>
```

2)If you want a JavaScript Alternative

```
<script src="http://cdn.webrupee.com/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you add the above script reference in the HEAD area of your webpage, all uses of "Rs." or "Rs" will be converted to Indian rupee symbol.

3)If the computer supports Unicode 6.0, then Indian rupee symbol can be displayed in the webpage using the following HTML code: [&#x20B9] ₹