# Indian currency is inconsistent on my webpage

Tags: jquery

How can I edit globalize.culture.en-IN.js file from globalize jQuery package?
ASP.Net framework displays ₹ as Indian currency symbol where as the above js file has Rs. as Indian Currency which is why currency is inconsistent on webpage. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the symbol in the third party library (with the permission of the developer). That worked, however, ₹ was getting displayed as box in the charts. Reason to this was that default font of FusionChart is Verdana which still doesn't support ₹ Unicode. Changed it to Arial and now everything working well.

For reference: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/fontsupport.htm

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest changing the js file from the jQuery package. If there are further updates to the package, you might have to incorporate your changes again accordingly. Its better to write your own script for your case.

Comment: It looks like the symbol "₹" is not supported by the package you're using. Look for an alternative lib which uses it correctly or write your own implementation to show the correct symbol but changing 3rd party packages is not always advisable.

Comment: True. I have contacted package owner. I will try other ways. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

WebRupee is the service which provides support for indian currency

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webrupee
Look at the use section. its very simple

Following link aslo has detailed solution.

[Displaying the Indian currency symbol on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598085/displaying-the-indian-currency-symbol-on-a-website)