# Add Rupee symbol in the text box

Tags: html, unicode, symbols

How can i add Indian Rupee Symbol inside a text box field and do not use Rs.

Amount: `<input name="amount" type="text" size="20" value="Rs. 1.00">`

In this i need to show "Rs." in terms of a symbol, as how we use "$".

Comment: check these links 
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-and-Use-Indian-Rupee-Symbol-in-Windows  http://www.labnol.org/india/windows-fonts-for-rupee/18964/

Comment: can't you just use the symbol ₹ by copy pasting it?

Comment: i tried but its showing me a square box... included font also.. but symbol is not coming.

Comment: seems like similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598085/displaying-the-indian-currency-symbol-on-a-website

Comment: @shemy thanks but i've gone through that link.. but i want it inside 'textbox'... and text inside 'textbox' is hardcoded..

Comment: you can try out this:       <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webrupee.com/font">
    <script src=http://cdn.webrupee.com/js type=”text/javascript”></script>
</head> <input type="text" class="WebRupee" value="Rs." readonly>

Comment: Text inside the `value` attribute of `input` is no more hardcoded than any other text on a page, so this *is* a duplicate.

Comment: If you have problems with having the symbol displayed, as you do, search for questions with the word “rupee” in them. (This question only asks how to add the character, so “just use the symbol ₹” and “use a character reference” are correct answers to what was asked.)

Answer (score 4):

According to me you shouldn't do this, whether you are saving the value in the database, or you are using to calculate something or anything else, simply store the integer, and than concatenate the `Rs.` or the rupee sign with the integer. This way it won't trouble you while calculating or storing values.

As far as the rupee symbol goes, you can use `&#x20B9;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TggE7/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/TggE7/1/) (Recommended)

---

**Even Better Solution**

I've made a demo from scratch which uses `background-image`, this way, your `text` field will indicate that the value is a rupee, also, it will be cross browser.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TggE7/2/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/TggE7/3/) (Using `background-size` to make image tiny)

```
input[type=text].rupee {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Fd7NROx.png);
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px; /* Indent the text values inside textbox */
    background-size: 20px 25px; /* Change symbol size */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* So that rupee image doesn't repeat */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use #8360;

```
<input name="amount" type="text" size="20" value="&#8360; 1.00">
```

Comment: i dont want to show it as text i.e."Rs." i want to show it as a symbol

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

Just include the following javascript and it will update all the " Rs " to " Rupee Symbol " for you
`<script src="http://webrupee.anmoul.com/js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

or Simply Use rupee symbol Unicode character code &#x20B9

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

css

```css
 .customTextfield input{
 border:unset;
  
}
.customTextfield input:focus{
  outline:unset;
}
.customTextfield{
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<span class="customTextfield">
  &#x20B9; <input name="amount" type="text">
</span>
```