# How to display Indian currency symbol instead of Rs

Tags: html, web, fonts, webfonts

I want to display Indian currency symbol instead of Rs in webpages,I've found different solutions for it in SE itself from all those solutions I want to go for the answer given by 
[OM The Eternity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5351571/1111502)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'rupee';
    src: url('rupee_foradian-1-webfont.eot');
    src: local('Ã¢ËœÂº'), url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,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)
    format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

<span style="font-family:rupee;font-size:20px">R</span>
```

In above approach I want to show rupee symbol instead of **Rs** not for **R**,is any idea to do this change ?

Comment: I want go for above approach because if I use unicode character it may not support in all browsers.

Answer (score 4):

**HTML Way**

The HTML code for the Rupee symbol is `&#8377;`  will look like  ₹

**CSS Way**

if you want to achieve this by `css` then

Add reference to in head for   `href=http://cdn.webrupee.com/font` .

Now in the body section type the following where ever you want to display the Rupee symbol.

```
<span>Rs.</span> 200
```

**Unicode Way:**

The Unicode is `&#x20B9;` will result in ₹

**Note:** *The usage of Unicode to display Rupee symbol in websites is limited as the Unicode will only be converted on the systems with Unicode version 6.0. If an user with lower Unicode version visits your site then he will not be able to see the Rupee symbol*.

Comment: I know this approach,its taking lot of time to load above mentioned link So,I thought to go mentioned approach in my question.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var str=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace(/Rs./gi,"<img src='http://www.myiris.com/insurance/images/rupee_icon.gif'/>");

//you can add ur local indian curruncy logo image file....

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;
```

Answer (score -1):

Download Rupee Foradian font from [here](http://www.fonts101.com/fonts/view/Standard/57559/Rupee_Foradian)

Define this style in CSS or in head section of page

```
<style>
@font-face
    {
    font-family: 'rupee_foradianregular';
    src: url('fonts/rupee_foradian-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/rupee_foradian-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/rupee_foradian-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/rupee_foradian-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/rupee/rupee_foradian-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/rupee_foradian-webfont.svg#rupee_foradianregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
.rup_foradian {font-family: 'rupee_foradianregular' !important;}
</style>
```

Then in HTML Page use code below

```
<span class="rup_foradian">`</span>
```

In Rupee Foradian Font ( ` ) stand for Rupees Symbol

[Vrudhee Solutions](http://www.vrudheesolutions.com)