# How to Display Indian currency by using standard data string format in c#.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to display a Indain rupee symbol in my web-site. in my grid view when I use DataFormatString="{0:c2} it is showing $ symbol.

so any one tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598085/displaying-the-indian-currency-symbol-on-a-website

Comment: Hello Shekhar My question is not same. I want Indian rupee symbol while I am fetching data from Grid View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be better off by setting the culture.

This can be done site-wide in the web.config, using the `<globalization uiCulture="in" culture="in-IN" />` element, or at the page level in the page directive `<%@ Page UICulture="in" Culture="in-IN" %>`

(it is in-IN or hi-IN am not too sure)

Or simply this for one-off scenario: `DataFormatString = ₹ + "{0:c2}";`

Comment: thank you very much for ans. I have changed my code to <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" CodeFile="Search.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Search_aspx" Title="Search"  UICulture="hi-IN" Culture="hi-IN" %>

Answer (score 1):

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-IN"/>
</system.web>
```

/* To get a Rupees Symbol in WebForm include   in system.web File under Web.Confiq */

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `UICulture` to `hi` and `Culture="hi-IN"` will display the Hindi Symbol: `रु`  for Rupees. [ Hindi is a language of India ]

If you want to display the symbol `₹` for an Indian Rupee, you can set the `CultureInfo` and customize the currency sign for the Culture.

// Override the `InitializeCulture()` method in your code behind file.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
  {

     CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
     // assign your custom Rupee symbol of your country
     ci.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "&#8377;";
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture 
                                            = ci;

     base.InitializeCulture();
  }
```

Now in your GridView you only need to specify the `DataFormatString="{0:C}"` and `HtmlEncode` as `false`.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" DataFormatString="{0:C}"
     HtmlEncode="false" />
```

Comment: Glad to know this helped you