# how to reslove currency convertion issues in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, converters, currency

Recently i have developed one application in cakephp. there is one option called change language. if i choose language it convert language properly but it shows Indian rupee symbol as text And instead of rupee symbol. please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598085/displaying-the-indian-currency-symbol-on-a-website

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NumberHelper` class function called `addFormat` to define your own currency, and you can then specify how this currency should be printed on the site.

Here is an example from the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/number.html#NumberHelper%3a%3aaddFormat):

```
App::uses('CakeNumber', 'Utility');
CakeNumber::addFormat('BRL', array('before' => 'R$', 'thousands' => '.', 'decimals' => ','));
```

[http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/number.html#NumberHelper::addFormat](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/number.html#NumberHelper%3a%3aaddFormat)