# Indian Rupee Symbole Not Showing on windows (7,8) Even it is showing on Linux

Tags: php, html

I am using html Code `&#8377;` to display Indian currency symbol on my website. But on Linux platform it showing symbol. But on windows platform it is showing rectangle symbol not rupee symbol. Can anybody Help me why it happening.

Thanks Advance

Code:

```
<th>Amounts AS ON 31-03-{{currentYear1}}<br>( &#8377; )</th>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: <th>Amounts AS ON 31-03-{{currentYear1}}<br>( &#8377; )</th>

Comment: Please check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598085/displaying-the-indian-currency-symbol-on-a-website

Comment: Thanks dude its working..

Comment: Refer: [Comprehensive Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37643800/2142994)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best suitable answer that seems to me from my given link is:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
Current Price: <i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 400.00
```